# using Future.wait() in Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor

Running subscriptions in async mode with `new Future()` works fine but if the same thing is done in a `Meteor.method` the application crashes with a message that it can not wait without a fiber. But I have to return something from the `Meteor.method`

This is the method:

```
/**global variables*/
var Fiber = Npm.require("fibers");
var Future = Npm.require("fibers/future");

Meteor.methods({
'single-data': function (form, state, tenant, selectedRow, search, sort) {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
  /**check if the user can see the data in the state*/
  if (!(isAdmin(user, form) || hasPermission(user, form, state, "read"))) {
     return null;
  }

  /** set the sort order for the query*/
  var order = [];
  if (sort) {
     order.push(["fieldData." + sort.column + ".0.value", sort.order == 1 ? "asc" : "desc"]);
  }
  order.push(["submitTime", "desc"]);

  var query = dataQuery(form, state, _.uniq(_.pluck(user.groups, "tenant")), search);

  var fut = new Future();
     var fut = new Future();   setTimeout(function () {
        fut.ret(FormDatas.find(query, {sort: order, skip: selectedRow, limit: 1}).fetch()[0]);
     }, 0 * 1000);

  // Wait for async to finish before returning the result
  return fut.wait();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the return value from future should not contain asynchronous code, it should happen before calling `ret()`. Anyway, in your case future is not needed, simply call

```
return FormDatas.findOne(query, options);
```